# sudo rm -rf returns "cannot remove directory" on empty directory owned by root

Tags: linux, directory, rm

I have a directory on my Debian system.  The directory is:

```
root@debian:/3/20150626# stat 00
File: `00'
Size: 6             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fe00h/65024d    Inode: 4392587948  Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-06-25 20:00:00.086150791 -0400
Modify: 2015-07-07 12:39:04.174903234 -0400
Change: 2015-07-07 12:39:04.174903234 -0400
Birth: -
```

The directory is empty:

```
root@debian:/3/20150626# ls -al 00
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  6 Jul  7 12:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 23 Jul  7 12:56 ..
```

But my system doesn't think so:

```
root@debian:/3/20150626# rm -rf 00
rm: cannot remove `00': Directory not empty
```

I don't know why this would happen nor am I able to find a way to move forward.  Can anyone provide assistance?

None of the previous questions that I could locate solved this specific issue.  But, to address some of the questions I've seen asked on similar posts:

a.)  The folder was created by a running process, which has created many folders before and these folders have been removed many times before.  This specific one is stuck in limbo.

b.)  There should not be anything written to this directory now.  I have checked many times and the `ls -al` output always returns nothing.

c.)  I have checked lsof and there is nothing open for this directory:

```
root@debian:/3/20150626# lsof 00
root@debian:/3/20150626#
```

d.)  `rm` is not aliased to anything else.  It's pretty close to stock Debian...nothing special done with any of the core Bash programs such as `rm`, etc.

e.)  Renaming is permitted but still unable to delete:

```
root@debian:/3/20150626# mv 00 delete_me
root@debian:/3/20150626# ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  30 Jul  7 13:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 105 Jul  7 12:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   6 Jul  7 12:39 delete_me
root@debian:/3/20150626# rm -rf delete_me
rm: cannot remove `delete_me': Directory not empty
root@debian:/3/20150626# ls -al delete_me/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  6 Jul  7 12:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 30 Jul  7 13:45 ..
```

**Note, hereafter referring to as "delete_me" since I renamed it and I'm just going to go with the flow.

f.)  This is the only directory that is returned when I run `find` on it.

```
root@debian:/3/20150626# find / -type d -name delete_me
/3/20150626/delete_me
root@debian:/3/20150626# find delete_me
delete_me
```

g.)  lsattr shows nothing:

```
root@debian:/3/20150626# lsattr
---------------- ./delete_me
```

Comment: Is it possible to rename the directory?

Comment: The "Links: 3" part jumps out to me; it seems as though you might have a subdirectory. What does "find 00" return?

Comment: Updated my question with an answer to yours, @JennyD

Comment: Updated my question with an answer to yours, @JeffSchaller

Comment: Have you checked `lsattr` to see if there are any special attributes assigned to it?

Comment: Updated my question with an answer to yours, @Caja

Comment: Try just `lsattr` in the parent directory of delete_me.

Comment: @Caja I don't know of an attribute which could make the file invisible, but what Jeff Schaller said is interesting; it looks like something is corrupted. Try to run `sync` and see if something changes after that

Comment: It's looking increasingly likely to me that this running process from item (a) is holding on to a subdirectory of "delete_me" in some fashion. Can you stop this running process, then re-check `stat` output (and/or retrying the rmdir)?

Comment: I have run `sync`, no change.  I have stopped every process that I have created or am responsible for in some form or fashion and it still says "Links: 3" when I run `stat`.

Comment: this is a mount.  Should I try `umount` then `mount` and see if it changes anything?  I do not wish to proceed without your suggestions.

Comment: It's an NFS mount? Certainly can try unmount/remount; also, can you log in to the NFS server to see what the server side looks like?

Comment: I'm not as fluent in storage speak as other things so hopefully I get this right - this is a logical volume on a volume group (?) on a RAID that is just mounted.  It's a local xfs mount.  `/dev/mapper/vg3-lv3 on /3 type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,delaylog,nobarrier,inode64,allocsize=1024k,logbufs=8,logbsize=256k,noquota)`

Comment: If you're able to, go ahead and try to unmount it -- `cd /; umount /3`. If there is a process with an open file in there, umount will complain about it being busy. Otherwise, if it successfully unmounts, re-mount it and see what `stat` shows again.

Comment: `umount /3` and `mount -a` resulted in my mount returning a-okay but `stat delete_me` showed the same: "Links: 3" and I am unable to remove.  Exact same as before.  I also rebooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  Something was wrong with the linkage, as @JeffSchaller suggested.  The solution is to run xfs_check to see that the links were incorrect, then xfs_repair to fix them.

1. run `mount` to view the device name.  Mine is `/dev/mapper/vg3-lv3`
2. `umount /3`
3. `xfs_check /dev/mapper/vg3-lv3` which returned the following:

   `link count mismatch for inode 4392587948 (name ?), nlink 3, counted 2`

   `link count mismatch for inode 12983188890 (name ?), nlink 1, counted 2`
4. `xfs_repair /dev/mapper/vg3-lv3` which indicated that the links were corrected:

   `resetting inode 4392587948 nlinks from 3 to 2`

   `resetting inode 12983188890 nlinks from 1 to 2`

Turns out I had another inode that was linked incorrectly.

Thanks for all the help but using the black magic of xfs_repair, my problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

You tried to verify that the attributes of the folder / directory have the attribute "**i**" - imutable is active! Check with the  ***lsattr***  command to verify that the folder / directory has the attribute "**i**" activate if you turn it off with "*

> chattr -i '*folder*'

*" With this you can perform the task you want.

Comment: The `-i` attribute on a file / folder doesn't prevent it from showing up, however where do you see that `-i` is set? OP's output is stating the opposite