# rm -fr fails to remove directory due to "Is a directory" error

Tags: files, rm, corruption

Recently noticed that one of my CentOS NFS clients have a directory which looks somewhat corrupted:

CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

```
[root@LG-B8A-LNX ~]# ls -lathr /
ls: cannot access /zebra: No such file or directory
total 134K
d??????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? zebra
```

Remove attempts failed:

```
[root@LG-B8A-LNX ~]# rm -fr /zebra
rm: cannot remove `/zebra': Is a directory
```

As well as lookup attemps:

```
[root@LG-B8A-LNX ~]# stat /zebra
stat: cannot stat `/zebra': No such file or directory
```

In the past this folder was used as a mount point to an NFS server

Can this directory entry be deleted in some way?

Comment: You'll probably need to fsck the filesystem.

Comment: @muru Thanks, but if it safe to run it on mounted filesystem? `fsck /` gives me warning that  /dev/sda3 is mounted

Comment: No, not at all. You'll probably have to boot to a recovery mode, or use a live system.

Comment: are you using fuse?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214428/sudo-rm-rf-returns-cannot-remove-directory-on-empty-directory-owned-by-root

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No, but this folder was used as a mount point to nfs server

Comment: Please add that to the question.

Comment: Is `/zebra` still listed in the output of `mount`? If not, how did you unmount it?

Comment: @roaima It's not listed. I didn't unmount, client was rebooted but I can't say if issue occurred before or after reboot

Comment: So the issue is ongoing, but there's nothing been mounted on `/zebra` since the most recent reboot?

Comment: @roaima Yup, the problem I can't actually say when did it started. It was sure mounted before reboot... Right now nothing mounted on that directory

Comment: Nothing's been mounted on that directory at all, since the reboot?

Comment: @roaima Indeed, nothing

Answer (score 1):

Check the `/etc/mtab`, maybe there is a line that still points the directory to the NFS mount. Also check if you have automount service running in the server.

Try `lsof | grep /zebra` to find any process that may be still using `/zebra`.
Also try `umount -l /zebra`, and `rm -rf` again.

Comment: Sorry, `~]# lsof /zebra lsof: status error on /zebra: No such file or directory`